# SQL - A simpler function than decode

Tags: oracle, plsql, decode

I am working with a pl/sql procedure. I have an initialized variable myvar and I want to check its value : if it does not contain 'Z', I want it to contain 'P'.

I am currently doing it this way:

```
myvar := decode(myvar,'Z','Z','P');
```

I was just wondering if there was a simplier way to do this. I mean, decode is already simple, but I feel it's weird to specify the content of the variable while it is already in it !

If such a function would exist, it would look like this:

```
Function myfunction(a In Varchar2, b In Varchar2, c In Varchar2) 
Return Varchar2 
Is               
Begin
      if a <> b
      then
           return c;
      end if;
      return a;
End myfunction;
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: DECODE is a SQL function, not a PL/SQL function. So your "myvar := decode ..." will not work.

Comment: @Rob. As far as I know, nothing prevents one from using a SQL function in a PL/SQL program. Anyway, decode works fine in my procedure.

Comment: not with decode.  SQL> declare
  2    myvar varchar2(1);
  3  begin
  4    myvar := decode(myvar,'Z','Z','P');
  5  end;
  6  /
  myvar := decode(myvar,'Z','Z','P');
           *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 12:
PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'DECODE' may be used inside a SQL statement only
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that function of yours to the program's declaration section and use it!

Comment: I had not thought about it, maybe it was too obvious ! It is a bit heavier than the case methode, but it makes my code a little simplier since I use it several times in my procedure.

Answer (score 14):

There is no built-in function that does exactly what you want.

You could use CASE rather than DECODE:

```
CASE myvar WHEN 'Z' THEN 'Z' ELSE 'P' END
```

It doesn't make it any shorter though!

Comment: It's the cleanest way to do it in my opinion, but as you said it is not shorter !

Answer (score 2):

I agree the best option is to use [CASE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/expressions004.htm#i1033392) expression:

```
CASE myvar WHEN 'Z' THEN 'Z' ELSE 'P' END
```

Another approach if you feel happy with [DECODE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions049.htm#i1017437) is to run this query:

```
SELECT decode(myvar,'Z','Z','P') 
  INTO myvar
  FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Your CASE option is preferred; you get a performance overhead when you force a SQL context switch.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question of whether there is a simpler way, there is also this:

```
if myvar <> 'Z' then 
  myvar := 'P'
end if;
```